# Trying to make a quiz with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Javascript and I was trying to create a quiz with jQuery but can not solve one big problem.

When I click in the "next" button all the answers are deleted... and I can not understand why.

PS: Can someone give me feedback about my code?

```js
var questionsOrder = [];
var currentQuestion = 0;

var allQuestions = [{
    question: "1Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
    correctAnswer: 0
}, {
    question: "1United Kingdom?",
    choices: ["David Camerfafaon", "Gordonfffa Brown", "Winstfafaon Churchill", "Tony fafaBlair"],
    correctAnswer: 0
}, {
    question: "2Who is Prime Ministerfsafasfa of the United Kingdom?",
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
    correctAnswer: 1
}, {
    question: "3Who ifafa Minister of the Unitedsafafgdom?",
    choices: ["David Caafameron", "Goasfarown", "Wiasfsfa Churchill", "TofasfaBlair"],
    correctAnswer: 2
}, {
    question: "4Who is Prime Minister oafsafaf the United Kingdom?",
    choices: ["David asfsafCameron", "Gordon asfasf", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blfsafasfair"],
    correctAnswer: 3
}];

var deleteOlQuestion = function () {
    $(".question").children().slideUp(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $(".answers").children().slideUp(function () {
        $(".answers").html(" ");
    });
    console.log("apagadas");
};

var shuffle = function (array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
};

var changeQuestion = function (question) {
    $(".question").slideDown(function () {
        $(".question").html("<h1>" + allQuestions[questionsOrder[currentQuestion]].question);
    });
    $(".answers").slideDown(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[questionsOrder[currentQuestion]].choices.length; i++) {
            var question = allQuestions[questionsOrder[currentQuestion]].choices[i];
            if (i == allQuestions[questionsOrder[currentQuestion]].correctAnswer) {
                $(".answers").append('<input type="radio" name="question" class="question" value=' + i + '>' + question + "<br>");
            } else {
                $(".answers").append('<input type="radio" name="question" class="question" value="not">' + question + "<br>");
            }
        }
    });
};

$("#start").on("click", function () {
    for (var index = 0; index < allQuestions.length; index++) {
        questionsOrder.push(index);
    }
    shuffle(questionsOrder);
    changeQuestion(currentQuestion);
    $("#start").css("display", "none");
    $("#next").css("display", "inline");
});


$("#next").on("click", function () {
    if ($('.question').is(':checked')) {
        if (+$("input:checked").val() === allQuestions[questionsOrder[currentQuestion]].correctAnswer) {
            // blink blink verde
            currentQuestion++;
            deleteOlQuestion();
            changeQuestion(currentQuestion);
        } else {
            alert("Wrong");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.quizBody {
    text-align: center;
}
#next {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quizBody">
    <div>
        <div class="question col-md-12"></div>
        <div class="answers col-md-12"></div>
        <div class="next col-md-12">
            <button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
            <button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have not inserted your code.

Comment: Likely a document.write after page load or a parent selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a timing issue ... I commented out this line ...

```
// $(".answers").html(" ");
```

... in `deleteOlQuestion`. Then, put it before the for-loop in `changeQuestion` and it works, sort of.

This should give you enough direction to move forward.

Working code snippet:

```js
var questionsOrder = [];
var currentQuestion = 0;

var allQuestions = [{
  question: "1Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
  choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
  correctAnswer: 0
}, {
  question: "1United Kingdom?",
  choices: ["David Camerfafaon", "Gordonfffa Brown", "Winstfafaon Churchill", "Tony fafaBlair"],
  correctAnswer: 0
}, {
  question: "2Who is Prime Ministerfsafasfa of the United Kingdom?",
  choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
  correctAnswer: 1
}, {
  question: "3Who ifafa Minister of the Unitedsafafgdom?",
  choices: ["David Caafameron", "Goasfarown", "Wiasfsfa Churchill", "TofasfaBlair"],
  correctAnswer: 2
}, {
  question: "4Who is Prime Minister oafsafaf the United Kingdom?",
  choices: ["David asfsafCameron", "Gordon asfasf", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blfsafasfair"],
  correctAnswer: 3
}];

var deleteOlQuestion = function() {
  $(".question").children().slideUp(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  $(".answers").children().slideUp(function() {});
  console.log("apagadas");
};

var shuffle = function(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
};

var changeQuestion = function(question) {
  $(".question").slideDown(function() {
    $(".question").html("<h1>" + allQuestions[questionsOrder[currentQuestion]].question);
  });
  $(".answers").slideDown(function() {
    $(".answers").html(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[questionsOrder[currentQuestion]].choices.length; i++) {
      var question = allQuestions[questionsOrder[currentQuestion]].choices[i];
      if (i == allQuestions[questionsOrder[currentQuestion]].correctAnswer) {
        $(".answers").append('<input type="radio" name="question" class="question" value=' + i + '>' + question + "<br>");
      } else {
        $(".answers").append('<input type="radio" name="question" class="question" value="not">' + question + "<br>");
      }
    }
  });
};

$("#start").on("click", function() {
  for (var index = 0; index < allQuestions.length; index++) {
    questionsOrder.push(index);
  }
  shuffle(questionsOrder);
  changeQuestion(currentQuestion);
  $("#start").css("display", "none");
  $("#next").css("display", "inline");
});


$("#next").on("click", function() {
  if ($('.question').is(':checked')) {
    if (+$("input:checked").val() === allQuestions[questionsOrder[currentQuestion]].correctAnswer) {
      // blink blink verde
      currentQuestion++;
      deleteOlQuestion();
      changeQuestion(currentQuestion);
    } else {
      alert("Wrong");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.quizBody {
  text-align: center;
}

#next {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quizBody">
  <div>
    <div class="question col-md-12"></div>
    <div class="answers col-md-12"></div>
    <div class="next col-md-12">
      <button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
      <button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```